# Where to tar entire USB flash drives?

Tags: ubuntu, tar, disk

I want to do all my archiving and compression on the command line. I have a *USB flash drive* located at `/dev/disk/by-label/SanDiskData` (which links to `/dev/sdc1`). I thought I could simply do:

> $ cd /dev/disk/by-label
>   $ sudo tar cfv ~/data.tar SanDiskData

But then the size of `/home/data.tar` is only `10 kB`.

Where can I `tar` entire *USB flash drives* on the command line?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are supposed to [`mount`](http://linux.die.net/man/8/mount) the drive before you can access its filesystem. Only if mounted you can execute filesystem operations (that is, access individual dirs and files) like `tar` on it via the *mountpoint* instead of the device node (or some symlink to it).